# Cannot find adb tool during running ndk-gdb

Tags: android, gdb, cygwin, android-ndk, gdbserver

I am building my android ndk application by using ndk-build commend and it works fine but, when i use ndk-gdb commend from cygwin i get a following error ;

```
    ERROR: The 'adb' tool is not in your path.
           You can change your PATH variable, or use
           --adb=<executable> to point to a valid one.
```

Please help me out to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its seems to be like, your instruction command can't find your **adb executable**,

So either **set environment path for adb.exe** or **give full path of your adb.exe in command**..

Answer (score 1):

You can add this commend to file: `cygwin/home/<username>/.bash_profile`

```
PATH=$PATH:"/cygdrive/e/Program Files/Java/jdk1.6.0_10/bin:/cygdrive/D/android-ndk-r8b:/cygdrive/e/android-sdk/platform-tools"
export PATH
adb=/cygdrive/e/android-sdk/platform-tools
export adb
```

Answer (score 0):

Additionally: check whether your Android installation path has spaces embedded (`"C:\program files\Android"` for instance). If so, you can either change your installation path or use a tool like "`junction`" (from [SysInternals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/sysinternals)) to redirect your installation path. Of course you'll have to remember to set your environment path to this new route.